# NextAuth with middleware what am I doing wrong

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

This is the [...nextauth]route.ts
Log in only with Google

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {

    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    pages: {
          newUser: "/account/form"
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    prompt: "consent",
                    access_type: "offline",
                    response_type: "code"
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
          async session({ session, token, user }) {
              const newSession = {...session};
              newSession.user = {...session.user, role: user.role, id: user.id}

              return newSession;
          },
          async signIn({user, account, profile}) {
              return true;
          },
          async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
              return url
          },
          async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
              console.log(token, 'token')
              console.log(user, 'user')
              if (token || user) {
                      token.userRole = "admin";
                      return {...token};
              }
              return token;
          },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This is the middleware.ts:

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth(
   // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
   function middleware(req) {
     console.log(req.nextauth.token, 'req.nextauth.token')
   },
   {
   callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) =\> {
        console.log(token, 'token')
        return token?.userRole === "USER"},
      },
   }
)

export const config = { matcher: \["/account"\] }
```

Token is null in the console.log

I want to check if user role is USER to allow them to access account page. Something is wrong with the jwt token. The token in the middleware returns null